# Merge [cache-manifest] and [application-cache] into [html5-appcache]

Tags: discussion, support, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Please merge [cache-manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cache-manifest) and [application-cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/application-cache) into [html5-appcache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5-appcache). All describe the same feature from the HTML spec at https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/offline.html#appcache, but [html5-appcache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5-appcache) describes it most precisely, and has the highest number of questions of the three.

It’s true that *“application cache”* is the name for the general feature, and the cache manifest is a specific file format that’s used as part of the feature. But if you look through the questions tagged with [cache-manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cache-manifest), you’ll note that very few of them are questions specifically about the cache manifest syntax/details — instead they’re questions about the general feature, and so could have just as accurately tagged with [html5-appcache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5-appcache).